# JSF onclick refreshes page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

```
<h:commandButton  onclick="window.open('/page.html')" value="test" action="#{bean.myAction}"></h:commandButton>
```

After I click on above the browser appears to refresh the page and scroll to the top.

If I use "return false;" the action never runs.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are using the `"window.open('/page.html')"`, But if you want to open the page after the action command completes then do the following

```
<h:commandButton value="test" action="#{bean.myAction}">
    <f:ajax onevent="function(data){ if(data.status === 'success') window.open('/page.html')}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it DOES refresh the page, why wouldn't it? `h:commandButton` acts as a simple form submit. You'd need ajax call to not reload the whole page.

You might look at, for example, [primefaces component library](http://primefaces.org/), which has ready to use components that support fully ajax calls - see [`<p:commandButton>`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml).

As for `return false`, if you use it in `onclick`, it'll doesn't run action because it stops form from submitting and thus, simplifying, "doesn't go through bean".

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:commandButton onclick="window.open('/page.html')" value="test" action="#{bean.myAction}">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@none" />
</h:commandButton>
```

should do the trick without PrimeFaces ;)